# connection reset exception for large files

Tags: java, sockets, http

I have a custom http server where i try to read from my server's space to my browser.

For large files (>10MB) i get "connection reset exception '. For smaller files i am properly able to write to browser.

My server reads zipped content, where i wrap ZipInflaterInputStream inside a BufferedInputStream, and then server reads from the bufferedInputStream.
When i extract the zip and read it from FileInputStream it's working fine.

For this below is the code i have. "data" variable is of type BufferedInputStream and "outputstream" is of instance of SocketOutputStream.

```
try {
            if (requestMethod != Method.HEAD && data != null) {
                int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
                byte[] buff = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                while (pending > 0) {
                    int read = data.read(buff, 0, ((pending > BUFFER_SIZE) ? BUFFER_SIZE : pending));
                    if (read <= 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    outputStream.write(buff, 0, read);
                    pending -= read;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("bytes already read while exception thrown" + pending);
            throw e;
        }
```

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: It sounds more like your server is reading *uploaded* content, *from* the browser *to* the server. Please clarify.

Comment: r @EJP thanks for your answer...its server only writing the output to the outputStream which i get from clientSocket.getOutPutStream and the InputStream as i mentioned i got from my zipped content..

Comment: Could you say if you use a servlet in a servlet container, or directly use sockets ?